# Trying to access array offset on value of type null warning in php

Tags: php, session

So , i'm tying to use a session in my `paynow.php` from `server.php`  but i get a `Undefined variable $_SESSION` warning followed by the above warning.
Here is my   `server.php`

```
<?php
session_start()
  if (isset($_POST['request'])) {
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $value=200; 
    $price =$amount *$value;
    $query = "INSERT INTO payments (amount) VALUES ('$price')";
    $result =mysqli_query($db,$query);
    if($result){
        $_SESSION['cost'] = $price;
        header('location:paynow.php');
    } ?>
```

here is where i'm trying to use the session in   `paynow.php`

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cost'])) : ?>
   <p style="color: green;">Pay<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['cost']; ?> dollars</strong></p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

The data is sent to the database but the problem is that i cant use my session. Can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

I just did not `<?php include('server.php')?>` in my `paynow.php`

Comment: Please mark as resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
    I think you forgot to put a semicolon.
    <?php
    session_start(); <=== put it here at the end of the line
      if (isset($_POST['request'])) {$amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $value=200; 
       ...
        } ?>


Also you should start the session at the top of paynow.php

<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['cost'])) : ?>
   <p style="color: green;">Pay<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['cost']; ?> dollars</strong></p>
    <?php endif ?>
```